# layout-land is not working?

Tags: android, xml, layout, orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I did some researches about this question but I couldn't find my answer. So, yes I did create a folder under res called "layout-land" and I put a separate main.xml in it. I intentionally deleted some images in the main.xml in the layout-land and I noticed that these images were still there when I rotated the android phone to horizontal.

Many questions similar to mine are caused by adding onConfigurationChanged to manifest. But I did NOT add anything to manifest as explained by this link

[layout-land xml files does not work with onConfigurationChanged call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336614/layout-land-xml-files-does-not-work-with-onconfigurationchanged-call-back)

Comment: Please post the complete manifest tag for the activity in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you must check is whether you already have in your `Manifest.xml` `android:configChanges="orientation"` that means that you wish to control the state of your activity when the orientation changes. When there's an orientation change Android will destroy your activity and recreate new, so any data will be lost.

So you should use `onConfigurationChanged()` method or `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method.

I recommend to you read some tutorial.

Comment: What about android:ScreenOrientation? Should I put sensor or portrait?

Comment: it you can use if you want to disable rotation system activities. It's radical alternative. It's up to you how your application will behave.