# Mediaplayer reloads when going to landscape or to portrait in android

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have a situation with the android MediaPlayer object.
I'm playing a m3u8 file from a server and I was wondering if there's a way for the player to load the streaming only once?
What's going on is that I enter the activity, and when this is loading, I go and play the stream, but when I go landscape, the player reloads, causing the app to slow down a bit.
Here's my code, that handles the load thing:

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);         
final String urlStream = Constantes.URL_VIDEO;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startLoader();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream));  
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

Any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the device, the activity is destroyed and created again with the new configuration. If you don't use different layouts for the landscape/portrait modes, then you can use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest in that activity's tag.
In case of using different layouts, read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange
and this:
[layout-land xml files does not work with onConfigurationChanged call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336614/layout-land-xml-files-does-not-work-with-onconfigurationchanged-call-back)

Comment: I've tried with the links, with no success... I don't know if there's like an option kinda like youtube or any player, where the object itself goes fullscreen...